# Access mssql object in Azure Mobile Services Scheduler script

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to access a mssql object in a scheduled script.

In a api or table I do something like this

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql
    mssql.query(.....)
}
```

There is no request for me to get access to the object. The documentation indicates that I should be able to access it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554212.aspx

If I install mssql via npm the interface is different than what I'm using elsewhere in the app.

Is there a way I can access a provided mssql object similar to other script types?

Answer (score 1):

mssql is a global object and you can just use it in Azure Mobile Services

```
function mySchedulerScript() {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE";

    mssql.query(query, {
    ...
    });
}
```